# Pumping lemma definition!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, automata, pumping-lemma

I was studing Pumping lemma and I saw wondering and confusing definition,**"Pumping length"**.

Here is my problems:

**Question 1:**

Is pumping length = number of states in DFA?

**Question 2:**

If any string can be divided into $\{xy^iz$ | $ i≥ 0\}$ , why $\vert xy\vert ≤$ Pumping length ?

I know Pigeonhole principle and how it used to epxlain we have a loop in DFA.
But I dont know how to use Pigeonhole principle to proof $\vert xy\vert ≤$ pumping length .

**I tried but gather nothing:**

I also checked this links but nothing was clear to me:
[First link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326505/sipser-pumping-lemma-clarification)
[Second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423903/what-exactly-is-the-pumping-length-in-the-pumping-lemma)

Thanks for any kind of help ;)

Answer (score 1):

On your first question: This one is a bit ill-posed because you don't specify what (D)FA you are talking about. The PL only says that for every regular $L$, there exists some integer $p$ such that all words in $L$ of length at least $p$ can be pumped, i.e. it doesn't uniquely specify such a $p$ (of course one could fix that by requiring $p$ to be minimal).

If we take a look at the proof of the PL, we see that $p$ is chosen to be the number of states of a DFA recognizing $L$, so in that sense the answer to your question is yes, but as I laid out, the "pumping length" is really referring just to the specifically chosen $p$.

On the second question: This is usually stated as $|xy| \leq p$.
The idea of the PL is that the run of our DFA on some pumpable word can be segmented into three parts: One that leads to a loop ($x$), then the loop itself ($y$), and finally the part that leads from that loop to an accepting state ($z$). The proof argues that such a decomposition exists for all words of length at least $p$ by (as you said) employing the pidgeonhole principle.
Now, this same argument tells us that a loop must already occur after at most $p$ symbols and hence, $|xy|$ is at most $p$.

I want to close with saying that the PL can be completely stated without the term "pumping length" (see e.g. [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)) and if it causes you any trouble, you can always just disregard it.